# Invalid hash - Stripe (Creating Source)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Good day everyone so I'm creating a source on stripe with the payment method IDEAL using their library and I stumbled with this unusual error.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 'Invalid hash' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/ideal/stripe-php-4.13.0/lib/ApiRequestor.php:110 from API request 'req_S1FAI6czFIggdC' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/ideal/stripe-php-4.13.0/lib/ApiRequestor.php on line 110

That error only appears when I tried to add this line of code under the `owner` object below (pls refer to my actual code below), that causes the error even its on the right place to add.

```
 "address" => "Test Adress"
```

Actual Code:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("test_key_here");

$source = \Stripe\Source::create(array(
  "type" => $type,
  "currency" => $currency,
  "amount" => $amount,
  "statement_descriptor" => $product,
  "owner" => array(
    "phone" => $phone,
    "email" => $email,
    "name" => $name,
    "address" => "Test Adress" //this causes the error
  ),
  "redirect" => array (
    "return_url" =>  $returnUrl 
  ),
  "ideal" => array(
    "bank" => $bank  
  )
));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that `address` is not the street address, it's a hash that expects multiple sub-parameters (the line 1 and line 2, the city, etc.) as documented here: https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_source-owner-address

The code should be something like this:

```
$source = \Stripe\Source::create(array(
  "type" => $type,
  "currency" => $currency,
  "amount" => $amount,
  "statement_descriptor" => $product,
  "owner" => array(
    "phone" => $phone,
    "email" => $email,
    "name" => $name,
    "address" => array(
      "line1" => "Test line1",
      "city" => "My City",
      "postal_code" => "90210",
      "state" => "CA",
  ),
  "redirect" => array (
    "return_url" =>  $returnUrl 
  ),
  "ideal" => array(
    "bank" => $bank  
  )
));
```

Comment: hey @koopajah that make sense! and so I tried it and it works thanks mate! :)